# Android wifi list control

Tags: android, android-wifi

**I want to list Wifi networks. Is there a WiFi I'm looking for in the list? How do I control it? I don't want to be connected to the wifi. If you have a special WiFi network i want change ringer mode. For example, ssid:"helloworld". If there is helloworld in the list i want change ringer mode – Can you help me?**

Comment: what do you mean by new transactions?

Comment: I don't want to be connected to the wifi. If you have a special WiFi network i want change ringer mode. For example, ssid:"helloworld". If there is helloworld in the list i want change ringer mode

Answer (score 1):

There are two scenarios, when `WIFI` is disabled and when `WIFI` is enabled, so I write two `AsyncTasks` to check the `WIFI` states and connect to your desired `SSID/Network`.

```
//Connect to SSID if WiFi is Enabled
public class ConnectToSSID extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean>
            {
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Connecting...",
                            "Connecting to \""+SSID+"\" Please Wait...", true);
                }

                @Override
                protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                    final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    WifiConfiguration wifiConfig = new WifiConfiguration();
                    wifiConfig.SSID = String.format("\"%s\"", SSID);
                    wifiConfig.preSharedKey = String.format("\"%s\"", NetworkPass);
                    int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfig);
                    wifiManager.disconnect();
                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);
                    wifiManager.reconnect();
                    SystemClock.sleep(3000);
                    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                    NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                    return wifi.isConnected();

                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                    progress.dismiss();
                    if(result){
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully Connected to "+SSID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }else{

                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error Connecting to "+SSID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            }


//IF WiFi is disabled, Enable it and Connect to SSID
public class EnableWifiAndConnectToSSID extends AsyncTask<String, String, Boolean>
        {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                progress = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "Connecting...",
                        "Connecting to \""+SSID+"\" Please Wait...", true);
            }

            @Override
            protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
                final WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) MainActivity.this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                final WifiConfiguration config = new WifiConfiguration();
                config.SSID = SSID;
                config.preSharedKey = NetworkPass;
                if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
                    wifiManager.setWifiEnabled(true);
                }
                int networkId = wifiManager.addNetwork(config);
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(networkId, true);
                SystemClock.sleep(3000);

                ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                return wifi.isConnected();

            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                progress.dismiss();
                if(result){
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Successfully Connected to "+SSID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Error Connecting to "+SSID,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
```

And use them like this:

```
//Global Variable SSID;    
String SSID = "NetworkName";
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
                NetworkInfo wifi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
                if(wifi.isConnected()){
                    WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getSystemService (Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
                    WifiInfo info = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo ();

                    if(info.getSSID().equals(String.format("\"%s\"", SSID))){
                        //Already Connected
                    }else{
                        new ConnectToSSID().execute();
                    }
                } else{
                    new EnableWifiAndConnectToSSID().execute();
                }
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to be connected to the wifi. If you have a special WiFi network i want change ringer mode. For example, ssid:"helloworld". If there is helloworld in the list i want change ringer mode